# Is there any formula which should insert time which should not auto update in the excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to know is there any formula except `=NOW()` to insert time in an excel sheet also which should not update time automatically?

The formula `=NOW()` is working fine but the problem is that it is updating time automatically with system's clock. I want there should be any formula or method which should free the current time when once inserted.

Comment: I think you're looking for this answer http://superuser.com/a/141370/468548. Same thing is answered here by @n0gr1p.

Answer (score 5):

Why use a formula if you don't want it to update automatically? Just enter the date directly into the cell. A shortcut to enter today's date is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon).

Answer (score 1):

I've used a lot of circular formulas to do just this. The cell will populate when another cell is updated, but if the cell is already updated, it references itself (circular). When you turn on circular formulas in excel it also asks you how many times it should iterate, I think the default is 100 but you can lower that if you need to.
Short tutorials to explain:
http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/excel-tips-tricks/create-a-timestamp-in-excel-with-formulas/

Answer (score 0):

To have the value of `=NOW()` frozen in time, after entering the formula in a cell, just copy and paste it over itself with **Paste Values** enabled (access the **Paste Special** dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> after pasting).

Comment: dear friends @Mark Wallace,I know that ctrl+shift+; enters current time in the selected cell but i want some formula for this as my purpose is something different. please help...

Comment: dear @Andre Neves,,I know that ctrl+shift+; enters current time in the selected cell but i want some formula for this as my purpose is something different. please help..

Comment: dear @bdr9, ,I know that ctrl+shift+; enters current time in the selected cell but i want some formula for this as my purpose is something different. please help..

Answer (score 0):

Further to bdr9's correct answer, Ctrl+Shift+; inserts the time.  If you want date and time, do both, with a colon/space/separator-of-your-choice between them.