# How to insert the =now() function in a cell automatically when I write in another and hit enter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to know how to:

Automatically have the `=now()` function in the column B of Excel, only displayed in each cell (B1, B2, .. Bν) whenever I write something in column A in the respective cells (A1, A2, .. Aν).

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to fill the function `=Now()`, so it'll always show the current date; our you want to create a "timestamp" to know when data in the cell was entered?

Comment: timestamp is an option, what is the relevant function?

Answer (score 7):

**NEW ANSWER**

If you want to have a timestamp that does not recalculate you will need to use a technique called [Circular Formulas](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/circular-reference.html). This basically allows a cell to perform a function based on its own content.

You need to enable this functionality by going to File > Options > Formulas then ticking the `Enable iterative calculation`. Change the Number of iterations to `1`. Press OK and save your sheet.

```
=IF(A1<>"",IF(B1="",NOW(),B1),"")
```

**Explanation:**

The first `IF` is similar to the one in the original answer. It checks if `A1` is blank. `<>` is the logical operator meaning `not equal to`. The second `IF` checks itself and runs if content is entered into `A1`. If `B1` is empty it enters the current date and time otherwise it outputs the existing content (the original timestamp).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You could try this in B1:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",NOW())
```

**Explanation:**

`ISBLANK` is a logical test that tests if the target cell has any input. It returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
The `IF` is structured so that if the target cell is blank it will output an empty string. If there is any input entered into `A1` it will output the current time and date.

It should be noted that each time the sheet is recalculated the value outputted by `NOW()` will change to the current time.

---

**References:**

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2
- http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/excel-tips-tricks/create-a-timestamp-in-excel-with-formulas/

Comment: A well-crafted answer!

Comment: THANK YOU, first comment is that I have changed "," commas to ";" in order to work out and second commet: How to avoid recalculation?

Comment: @stagml I suspect that is down to your regional settings but happy to have helped!

Comment: How to avoid recalculation?

Comment: this is it? Menu > Excel Options > Formula > Calculation Options> Manual > Tick off "Recalculate Workbook before Saving"

Comment: Edited answer to explain circular references

Comment: @stagml I can't say that enabling circular references for this sheet won't cause issues down the road as it appears it's an application property. It'd probably be easier to copy - paste special - values. I gave this answer +1 earlier, so don't see this as me saying it's a bad answer.

Comment: Came here to answer this question with this answer! Circular references will be fine so long as that's all this particular spreadsheet does. I used this for an automatically timestamping call log. If you needed to do any analysis I'd recommend copying and pasting the raw data into another spreadsheet with circular references deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always wise to use VBA for everything, but this is a good candidate, especially if you want to track whenever a row was changed, and not just when it was first entered.  Insert the following into the code for the sheet with the timestamp column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim intersection As Range
    ' Change A:A,C:E to whatever range you want to watch.
    Set intersection = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A,C:E"))
    If Not intersection Is Nothing Then
        Dim r As Range
        For Each r In intersection.Rows
            ' Change B1 to whichever column is the timestamp.
            r.EntireRow.Range("B1").Value = Now
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In this example, columns A, C, D, and E are watched for changes, and when changes do occur, the current date and time is inserted into column B of the same row.

Comment: It should be noted that placing code in the Worksheet_Change() event will effectively disable undo for that worksheet because the undo stack is wiped every time VBA code that impacts workbook values is executed.