# Excel display time NOW in cells automatically on sheet change

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In my A1,A2,...,A10 cells i have this code

```
=IF(B1>0,NOW(),0)
```

So if B1>0 A1 equals to Date time now
and all this for
B2 and A2 
B3 and A3 and so on.

But the problem is that if i change for example B4 all cells from A1 to An automatically change to the date of A4 actually if i do something on this sheet
A1 ... An automatically change to the current Time NOW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically update cell in Excel with current timestamp when another cell is changed](http://superuser.com/questions/124818/automatically-update-cell-in-excel-with-current-timestamp-when-another-cell-is-c)

Comment: The normal behavior of NOW() is to update any time the sheet is recalculated.  Are you asking how to have it update only if a specific cell changes?  It isn't clear whether you're describing what you want to happen, or the problem of what does happen and you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short *Event Macro*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim B As Range, I As Range, cell As Range
   Set B = Range("B1:B10")
   Set I = Intersect(Target, B)
   If I Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      For Each cell In I
         If cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
         Else
            cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
         End If
      Next cell
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**