# prevent duplicates in excel is easy but

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, duplicate, data-validation

We all know how to prevent duplicates in excel by using data validation and the custom formula : `=COUNTIF($A:$A;A1)=1` for example.

but I need to add a time condition, so every day I'm typing some numbers in a row and these numbers must be unique in the that day.

So there must be no duplicates entries in the same day but can be typed tomorrow also one time and so on.

Comment: Store the date with the time and format the cell to not show the date perhaps?

Comment: the time is not an entry it's only a condition the numbers typed are the entries like if I type in A1 : 67 and I want to type it again in A2 I cant do it only today so if tomorrow I want to type 67 in A2 it's possible and so on

Comment: So you want it to prevent you entering duplicates on a certain day, but allow them again the next..?

Comment: Okay, where are you typing these? How many are you typing? What are they?

Comment: @Jonno yes you are exactly right but in the next day also no duplicates

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm typing only numbers, up to 300 per day, using a simple worksheet

Comment: So not all at once? What are they for?

Comment: @Raystafarian so I'm managing a groupe of people 300 exactly, each one has a number when they come to my shop I type their number to check, every one is allowed to come only once in a day so to prevent any fraud I need to prevent duplicates entries in the same day

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can figure something out.

Comment: You have to have the date entered onto your spreadsheet somehow. [this](http://superuser.com/questions/124818/automatically-update-cell-in-excel-with-current-timestamp-when-another-cell-is-c) post explains how you can do that. After that building the conditional formatting to check for duplicates is a simple manner of converting your `countif()` to `countifs()`

Comment: @Kyle I'm using a VBA code that print automatically the date+time I need only the last step :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should just work with a countifs

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,B1,$A:$A,A1)=1
```

Assuming dates are in A and numbers are in B.

Setup like this -

[image]

Now, let's see what happens with a repeat -

[image]

It works! But wait, what about different dates?

[image]

SUCCESS!

Comment: I'll try it right now

Comment: so when trying it I selected the A and B rows and applied the formula but not working

Comment: Apply it only to the B range

Comment: ok I'll try it now

Comment: tried it but not working also, so I'll try using the and + countif functions instead of countifs

Comment: it works only if you insert the date by hand wich is not a good thing to be doing all the day so the time must be used as a condition not entry somehow

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Make sure all other rules are removed. Even using `=today()` and `=today()-1` works. Try it on a blank sheet, or copy - paste values of your list and test it.

Comment: I tried it on a blank sheet but not working sorry can you please upload your example so I can see how it works. thank you very much

Comment: @SaidKhattabi see screenshots. That's the best I can do.

Comment: thanks a lot it gave me an idea now, but your solution needs the dates to be written before typing the number, my idea is when typing the numbers then the date + hour show up automatically and that I think is impossible.
thank you for your help :)

Comment: That would require a macro

Comment: I'm already using a macros to print the date and hour, but couldn't find a real solution so I did the following :
since I know there are 300 people I selected 300 cells and applied data validation on them for day 1,then selected other 300 cells and also applied data validation and so on it's working for me :), thank you all for the help :)

Comment: If you're already using a `worksheet_change` macro, you don't need data validation, you could just validate from the macro.