# Create latest update date excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to insert a last updated on () if any value in that row was changed.   I have a column for this in my spreadsheet. Applies only with actual values changed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tip: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change, record the time/day in a specific cell `Range(A1).value=*Date*`

Answer (score 0):

Automatic timestamping is unfortunately not available natively in Excel.

You either have to resort to coding VBA macros, or implement some semi-automatic timestamping technique. Unfortunately "semi-automatic" always relies on the user to take the appropriate action to record the timestamp.

Detailed info on each method is available in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/124818/automatically-update-cell-in-excel-with-current-timestamp-when-another-cell-is-c/1704735#1704735).

In short you can use "list" data validation where the list is set to =NOW(). This gives a dropdown list with the most recent timestamp, which the user can select and commit easily after each cell/row change.

Alternatively you can use circular formula, but requires a global Excel settings change which can affect any open workbook. It works quite well, but should be used with caution.

Lastly you can simply instruct users to hit a shortcut key:

```
CTRL and ; (to insert the current date)
CTRL SHIFT and : (to insert current time)
```